# laravel timestamps not working, delete the model but still can retrieve value?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\HR;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\models\HR\attendance;

class attendanceController extends Controller
{
    public function select()
    {
        return attendance::get();
    }
}
```

this is my route web.php

```
Route::get('attendance/select/','HR\attendanceController@select');
```

this is my model attendance.php

```
<?php

namespace App\models\HR;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class attendance extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

when i update on attendance model i had error unknown column `updated_at` which means i have to disable timestamps then i add

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

but it didn't work, i'm still getting unknown column `updated_at`. then i delete it

this is my directory structure with laravel, there are no attendance.php in HR folder neither elsewhere. But, i can retrieve value from it, how is that possible?

[image]

Comment: "_error unknown column updated_at_" doesn't necessarily mean you have to disable timestamps, you could also just add the columns in your table.

Comment: Does running `php artisan cache:clear` or `php artisan clear-compiled` do any good?

Comment: how about i've delete the attendance.php file in my folder but i can retrieve value using attendance::get() ? i'm so confused this whole day

Comment: still not working

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I meant `php artisan config:clear`, does that do anything? If not I can't help, sorry.

Comment: still not working, it's ok man thx

Comment: is there have a field name `updated_at` in your table `attendance`? if you  update your data , `laravel`  will add `set update=xxxx-xx-xx` in the query

Comment: @qskane there's only 4 field names: tanggal, user_id, masuk, keluar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm sorry. it is my mistake, i have copy `attendance.php` to other folder and it seems composer `autoload_classmap.php` point it to that folder

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Eloquent expects created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the  $timestamps property on your model to false:

you are missing `update_at` and `created_at` in your table `attendance`

in `laravel`, when you `update` or `create` data, `laravel` will default add someting like this `set update_at="YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss"`

so, you should add `update_at` and `created_at` to every table.

[laravel 5.6 document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)